# Twitter API: How to search only for geotagged tweets

Tags: api, search, twitter

How can I use `Twitter Search API` (or other) to get a list of tweets which have the `"geo"` param?

--EDIT--

By example: I wont get list of geotagged tweets, by #apple tag. Without location filter,  worldwide.

Comment: I want exactly the same. Do you manage to get it working?

Comment: The Twitter search API and the geo param will not work as you expect, it can still return results where no coords are provided (no lat/lng).

Answer (score 12):

Looks like the latest API supports that; simply use a large enough geo region for your query:

```
-180,-90,180,90
```

See more from the API link for [filter and location](http://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#locations)

Answer (score 9):

The streaming API allowed you to filter by a location and the search API allows you to search by geocode. You can find more information on these services on our developer resources site.

Streaming API: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api

> Example: Create a file called ‘locations’ that
>   contains, excluding the quotation
>   marks, the phrase:
>   “locations=-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8,-74,40,-73,41” then execute:
>
> curl -d @locations
>   http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json
>   -uAnyTwitterUser:Password.
>
> You will receive all geo tagged tweets
>   from the San Francisco and New York
>   City area.

Search API: http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search

> Example: `http://search.twitter.com/search.json?geocode=37.781157,-122.398720,1mi`

Comment: i read this, problem is that I do not want to restrict the location, but receive only geotagged tweets.

Comment: There is no way to do this with the current twitter api. What you are asking is for twitter to provide you a filtered feed of some sort - why would twitter waste bandwidth and server time for pre-filtering feeds? You WILL have to either download all feeds, filter them yourself, search for feeds within a radius or something of the like - it comes down to you doing the filtering.

Comment: "What you are asking is for twitter to provide you a filtered feed of some sort"... If I search with the param `geocode=37.781157,-122.398720,1mi`, as shown in your example, that is also a "filtered feed", insofar as requesting only geotagged tweets is a "filtered feed."  It's fine that there's no way to do this currently, and thank you for stating that, but providing that feature would waste no more server time than existing geotag filters and it would consume LESS bandwidth because we wouldn't have to pull down ALL tweets when we only want a subset.

Comment: I encountered the same question and after a bunch of googling, I summarized the method [here](http://yanzhe.postach.io/gathering-geo-tagged-tweets-using-twitter-streaming-api). Hope this can help others later.

Comment: @YanzheChen your side is currently down. I would be interested in the method if you have the information. Thanks

Comment: Needs to be updated with recent twitter API I think.

Answer (score 5):

From the `Twitter API` Documentation, this should be the format of your search query:

```
 http://search.twitter.com/search.json?geocode=37.781157,-122.398720,1mi
```

Where `37.781157` is the latitude, `-122.398720` is the longitude and `1mi` is the radius to search within.

Comment: So would specifying 10000000miles cover the whole earth and answer the OP's question? Would that work?

Comment: `# geocode Returns tweets by users located within a given radius of the given latitude/longitude. The location is preferentially taking from the Geotagging API, but will fall back to their Twitter profile. The parameter value is specified by "latitude,longitude,radius", where radius units must be specified as either "mi" (miles) or "km" (kilometers). Note that you cannot use the near operator via the API to geocode arbitrary locations; however you can use this geocode parameter to search near geocodes directly.
`

Comment: this request return any twitts with "geo" or without. i need get twitts ONLY with "geo" param in JSON.

Comment: once you are able to fetch a list of tweets in JSON format, you can sort them in a loop to see for the tweets that have GEO tagging done in them...

Comment: this is a very slow solution, but it seems no other way yet

Comment: are you trying to search the geo tagged tweets from all around the world?

Comment: yes, i try search the geo tagged tweets from all around the world.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for every tweet but save only the geotaged ones.
I know it dont make a lot of sense, but works quite well.

if you call you search results, you can state

```
for result in results:
    if result.geo != None:
        print result.text.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore')  # or do anything you want with the tweets
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `-180,-90,180,90` to get any geotagged tweet.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to [this earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17287405/3614835).