# Twitter API - how to only receive "geo" results?

Tags: twitter

Can this query be modified to only return results with a non-trivial "geo" value?

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?geocode=38.947,-77.090,39km&result_type=recent&page=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to search only for geotagged tweets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337319/how-to-search-only-for-geotagged-tweets)